# Why is this image replacement technique not working?

Tags: css, image, replace

I am trying to practice image replacement techniques, primarily for navigation purposes. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. The hover works, however the default menu item does not. I'm pretty sure things are written correctly.

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/practical/index.html

Here's the HTML fo the Navigation:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="process"><a href="index.html" id="active">Our Process</a></li>
    <li id="function"><a href="function.html">Bio-Built Function</a></li>
    <li id="future"><a href="future.html">The Future</a></li>
    <li id="engage"><a href="engage.html">Engage Dio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's my CSS for the Navigation:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    width: 244px;
    height: 124px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#nav li {
    float: left;
    }

#nav li a {
    width: 244px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background: url('../img/bg_nav.png');
    }

#process {
    background-position: 0 0;
    }

#process:hover {
    background-position: -244px 0;
    }

#function {
    background-position: 0 -31px;
    }

#function:hover {
    background-position: -244px -31px;
    }

#future {
    background-position: 0 -60px;
    }

#future:hover {
    background-position: -244px -62px;
    }

#engage {
    background-position: 0 -90px;
    }

#engage:hover {
    background-position: -244px -93px;
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... if it's to do with id="active", I don't see any CSS for that above?

Comment: If you look at the html file, all the links say "Our Process." I've tried to reposition the background, but it's not working for some reason, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one of the selectors you wrote there isn't matching with what I see on the website: `#nav li a` is `#nav li` on your website.

Second, you need to be careful about the CSS selector specificity:

```
#nav li
```

will overrule:

```
#process
```

but:

```
#nav #process
```

won't be overruled.

You can find a very good article about specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

I would include the:

```
#nav li a {
    width: 244px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background: url('../img/bg_nav.png');
    }
```

within the #process (which by the way classes might work better)

```
 #process {
        width: 244px;
        height: 30px;
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        background: url('../img/bg_nav.png');
```

get rid of #nav li a **in the CSS not the HTML**, and try this:

```
 #process {
        width: 244px;
        height: 30px;
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        background: url('../img/bg_nav.png');
        background-position: 0 0;
}

 #process:hover {
    background-position: -244px 0;
}
```

etc for function & others...

if I missed anything or if you have any questions please include in comments.